# Computer randomly slows down

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, suspend, cpu-load

Sometimes my computer slows down for no apparent reason. I was trying to find the culprit using htop, but it looks like this phenomenon affects the whole system, i.e. everything starts using a lot of CPU. Interestingly, if I suspend my computer and then wake it up, the problem goes away. Do you have any idea what could cause this? What kind of diagnostics should I run?

I'm running Xubuntu 20.04. RAM size: 12 GB, Swap: 2GB.

Comment: How much Memory and Swap do you have? The terminal command `free` will tell you. Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].

Comment: Many CPUs are throttled back when they get above a given temperature. The method varies from unit to unit.

Comment: @Gil could be onto something. Can you hear your fans running?

Comment: Normally not. I also checked the temperature with psensor. I was trying load my CPU (by opening some videos) to see what happens. First, my system slowed down for a few minutes even after I closed the videos. The second time nothing happened. I honestly have not idea what is going on.